Include Keyword in \footcite
im currently finishing my thesis, and i need to include a keyword (according to chicago syle) into my footnotes.
Im using \footcite[Cf.][page]{Entry} to cite, with \usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,style=verbose-inote,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex} for my biblatex.
This results in ^1 Cf. Doe, 1999, p. X.
But i need a Solution to get ^1 Cf. Doe, Keyword, 1999, p. X
How can i incorporate keywords, to match this style? (For Reference: https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_citationguide/citation-guide-1.html)
Thank you in advance!

This is not Chicago style. In author-date Chicago style you'd always just have author and year. In Chicago note style you'd have a full citation on first cite and "Name (Short)title" on subsequent cites (as shown in your link). What you describe is neither of these. You can get real Chicago style with biblatex-chicago.

Is this for the FOM? There is https://github.com/andygrunwald/FOM-LaTeX-Template, but the FOM guidelines seem to be ever changing, so it's anybody's guess if the template works for you.

@moewe this is for FOM, yes. I already told them that author, year would be better, but they insist on their keyword. I tried incorporating the github code, but i cant get it to work. I just need a solution to get the keyword into the footnote.

Maybe try the code from https://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=25659?
